# Chebyshev expansion of $\log(1 + x)$

Tags: chebyshev-polynomials

I was reading a Wikipedia article on [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) and got stuck in around the end of the article where the author takes advantage of orthogonality to compute the coefficients of the Chebyshev expansion of $ \log (x+1) $. I will be happy if someone explains the process to get 
$$a_0 = - \log(2)\quad\mbox{and}\quad a_n = \frac{- \pi (-1)^n}{n} \quad\mbox{ for $ n \in \mathbb{N} $.}$$ Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @stevengregory , my function is log(1+x) not 1+x.

Comment: So was mine. I made a typo. $a_0 = \displaystyle \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-1}^{1} \dfrac{\ln(1+x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx      = \frac{1}{\pi}(-\pi \ln 2)=-\ln 2$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that for $t\in (0,\pi)$,
$$
\begin{align}
\log(1+\cos(t))
&=\log\left(\frac{e^{it}+2+e^{-it}}{2}\right)\\
&=\log\left(1+e^{it}\right)+\log\left(1+e^{-it}\right)-\log(2)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{e^{int}}{n}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{e^{-int}}{n}-\log(2)\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{\cos(nt)}{n}-\log(2).
\end{align}
$$
Hence, by letting $x=\cos(t)\in (-1,1)$, we obtain
$$\log(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2(-1)^{n+1}}{n}T_n(x)-\log(2)T_0(x)$$
which implies that 
$$a_0=-\log(2)\quad\mbox{and}\quad
a_n=\frac{2(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\mbox{ for $n>0$}$$
where $\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n T_n(x)$,
  which is a bit **different** from what we read on the [wikipage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Example_1).

P.S. Going back to the wikipage:
\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^1\frac{\log(1+x)T_m(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx&=\int_{\pi}^0\frac{\log(1+\cos(t))\cos(mt)}{|\sin(t)|}\,(-\sin(t)dt)\\
&=\int_0^{\pi}\left(2\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{\cos(nt)}{n}-\log(2)\right)\cos(mt) dt\\
&=\begin{cases}
-\pi\log(2) &\mbox{if $m=0$,}\\
\dfrac{(-1)^{m+1}\pi}{m}&\mbox{if $m>0$.}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
On the other hand if $\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n T_n(x)$,
\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^1\frac{\log(1+x)T_m(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx&=a_m\int_{-1}^1\frac{T_m(x)^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx
=\begin{cases}
\pi a_0 &\mbox{if $m=0$,}\\
\dfrac{\pi}{2}a_m&\mbox{if $m>0$.}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Comment: I knew that property of orthogonality, my question was about the computation of $ a_n $ in case of $ f(x) = log(1+x) $. Thanks though!

Comment: Since $\cos nt=T_n(\cos t)$, you could have made the substitution $x=\cos t$ immediately. Integration of an infinite series term by term would need some justification; the series doesn't converge uniformly.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Good point! Thanks.

Comment: @AlPinky I edited my answer. Is it better now? Any further doubt?

Comment: @RobertZ, Yes, much better. Thanks man, I appreciate your help.